# HERE API - Pre Determined Route Toll Costs

Tags: gps, here-api, here-maps-rest

I would like to get toll costs for a pre-determined route using GPS coordinates and not link ID's.  I would like to use this request for I have the route the driver already took:

```
https://tce.api.here.com/2/tollcost.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&tollVehicleType=3
&vehicleNumberAxles=2
&emissionType=6
&height=3.5m
&vehicleWeight=10.0t
&limitedWeight=10.0t
&passengersCount=1
&tiresCount=8
&route=748873330,50;68614309,40;17357322,30;748938713,20;76719821,10;17357323,0
&detail=1
```

In the route section; how can I use only GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

With the Toll Cost Extension API, you can only specify the link IDs for the route parameter. You may want to use the Fleet Telematics API which gives you more flexibility in the toll cost calculation.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html